# unlisting a list while keeping the indices

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a list which can have either empty entries, entries containing one elements and entries containing multiple elements.

```
l1 = list(integer(0), 11L, integer(0), integer(0), 11L, 11L, c(6L, 
36L), 16L, 16L, integer(0), integer(0))
```

I would like to unlist l1 and create a data frame, where for the empty elements the index will not appear at all, and for multiple elements the index will appear multiple times:

```
df = data_frame(entry = c(2, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8, 9), element = c(11, 11, 11, 6, 
36, 16, 16))
```

so for example here entry 7 appears twice because the list has two elements there (6 and 36).

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can have two options.  Make the `list` a named one, `enframe` it to a `tbl_df` and then `unnest` the `list` element.  The `NULL` elements will be automatically removed

```
library(tidyverse)
l1 %>% 
     set_names(seq_along(.)) %>% 
     enframe %>%
     unnest
```

Or after naming the `list`, `stack` it to a 2 column data.frame

```
stack(setNames(l1, seq_along(l1)))[2:1]
```

Answer (score 3):

A "low level" solution:

```
data.frame(entry=rep(seq_along(l1),lengths(l1)),element=unlist(l1))
#  entry element
#1     2      11
#2     5      11
#3     6      11
#4     7       6
#5     7      36
#6     8      16
#7     9      16
```